# Energy density and internal density relations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy, density

If energy density relates to rest mass density as $\epsilon = \rho / c^2$. How internal energy relates to energy density?
Also, when do we write $\epsilon = \rho / c^2$ an when $\epsilon = \rho / c ^2 + €$?

Comment: It would help a lot if you explained what you denote by $\epsilon$, $\rho$, $c$ and $€$.

Comment: epsilon = energy density , rho= rest mass density,  c =speed of light,  e=internal energy

Comment: In this case your formulas are incorrect on dimensional grounds (did you mean $\epsilon = \rho c^2$?). What is "internal energy"?

Comment: The rest mass density $\rho$ for an one particle fluid or gas is given by:
$$\rho= m n,$$ where $n$ is the particle number density and $m$ is the particle mass.

The energy density $\epsilon$ of such a system is in general not $\epsilon\neq\rho c^2$. $\rho c^2$ is still the rest mass density just expressed in units of an energy density. Energy density includes things like binding energy or if you want thermal/kinetic energy. How the energy density is related to number density strongly depends on the system.

Answer (score 1):

The total energy density is the sum of all the individual types of energy density, for example: rest-mass, (or thermal/`pressure'), internal energy, but may also include electromagnetic, kinetic, etc

i.e. (Eq. 1)
$$\epsilon = \rho c^2 + € + ...$$  Note that it is mass-density **times** $c^2$, *not* divided by.

If some of the terms on the right-hand-side are zero (like velocity, magnetic field, or *internal energy*) then we can simplify to,

(Eq. 2) $$\epsilon = \rho c^2.$$
Equation (2) is a special case of equation (1).